# Error while generating HTML report using JMeter@5.4.3

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan and have got the results to a csv file. I am getting following error when trying to generate HTML report using that csv file.

An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5

I am using java 8 and jmeter 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

> I am using java 8

no, you are not, the bug [65685](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65685) is Java 17-specific so double check the Java version you're using.

It can be done using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) configured like:

[image]

then look for `java.version` system property in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

or alternatively you can check the actual Java version in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

[image]

If you cannot [install earlier version of Java](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) for some reason you can try out the [nightly build of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)

Comment: I have tried with both java 8 and java 18. Couldn't rectify the issue. :(